# in reflux, can't reuse Component throught global var

Tags: reactjs, refluxjs

i am try building for my project which used to reflux model, as you know, the reflux have:

```
myblog 
-actions
-stores
-conponents
-----register.js
-libs
-----react.js //or react.js add on, tried using
-----JSXTransformer.js
-----react-with-addons.js //or remove it, tried using
-----reflux.js
-test.html
```

- in components/register.js, i created a global.RegisterForm with code:

> > (function(React, global) { 
> >             global.RegisterForm = React.createClass({
> >                 render : function() {
> >                     return `<h2>Register Form</h2>`
> >                 }
> >             })
> >         })(window.React,  window);

- test.html:

> ```
> <html>
> <head>
>
>  <script src="libs/react.js"></script>
>  <script src="libs/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
>  <script src="libs/reflux.js"></script>
>  <script src="pages/register.js"></script>
>  <script type="text/jsx">
>
> (function(React, global) {
>
>   var RegisterPage = global.RegisterPage;
>
>   var App = React.createClass({
>
>       render : function() {
>
>           return (<RegisterPage />);
>
>       }
>   })
>
>     React.render(<App />, document.body)
>
> })(window.React,  window);
>
>  </script>
>
> </head>
> <body>
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

- error:
  [enter link description here](http://postimg.org/image/4xbe1li9z/)

do you think this error without router in reflux because i reffer to reflux-todo sample which have a router ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`register.js` is a JSX file but you're not transforming it which is why you get both errors.

To fix it you need to also set the type (i.e. `type="text/jsx"`) when [referencing the file](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html) in `test.html`:

```
<script type="text/jsx" src="pages/register.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Spoike, 
it doesn't work even i assigned to type="text/jsx". you can see the error with link: http://s1.postimg.org/9gj8wizjj/error_reflux_component.png. I think it need to router file, do you think that ?

Comment: @JimmyMac don't use file:/// urls, run a local web server.

Comment: thanks FakeRainBrigand for run a local web server and thanks Spoike for set the type. I made it.